# Want to use indexes on secondary collection of the mongodb

Tags: mongodb, performance, lookup, execution-time, mongodb-indexes

I have two collections **mainCol** and **joinedCol** from which using joins i am fetching around millions of records and the db query is taking excessive time, i want to use indexes on the fields of joined collection to reduce the excution time of the query.
Is there any other way to reduce the execution time ?
and how we will use indexes on the joinedCol of the query.

Suppose mainCol have fields (name, address, createdOn, fatherName) and joinedCol have fields (phoneNo, email). I use a $lookup to get data combined holding all the fields. But i need data of some particular names and with particular email, on mainCol fields i have created index on name and createdOn but i want to build indexes on the phoneNo and email for fast execution, on creating index on email and phone the index get's created but do not use and not give a single bit difference in execution time of the query.
How will i do so to make my execution of query fast using indexes or any other method?

Comment: You need to show us the query and the indexes on both collections.

Comment: Hey @Noel please visit this link once,     https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76107304/i-want-to-used-indexes-on-joined-collection-in-mongodb