# I want to used indexes on joined collection in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, indexing, lookup, mongodb-indexes

I have two collection named as *users* and *user_data*, *users* is a primary collection and   the *user_data* is a secondary collection. I have perform an aggregate query for retrieving millions of data but the query is taking too much time for execution. So, i try to use compound indexes on the fields of both the collections for e'g: audience_id: 1, contact.is_bounced: 1,   contact.not_valid: 1 but on the time of execution secondary collection indexes are not use. Is   there any way to use indexes on joined collection.

The problem is i am not able to get result on using indexes of secondary collections.

```
db.users.aggregate([{    
     $match: {    
     audience_id: {$in:      [ObjectId('633eaba80cb7a3b1d910e98b'),ObjectId('63b6a5325bf3f04f18170e84')]
  },    
      status: 'Subscribed'    
 }    
 }, {    
 $group: {
  _id: '$contact_id',
  contact_meta: {
   $first: '$$ROOT'
 }
 }
 }, {
 $lookup: {
  from: 'user_data',
  'let': {
   id: '$_id'
  },
  pipeline: [
   {
    $match: {
     $and: [
      {
       $expr: {
        $eq: [
         '$_id',
         '$$id'
        ]
      }
      },
    {
       email: {
        $exists: true,
        $ne: ''
      }
      },
    {
      $or: [
        {
         is_bounced: {
          $exists: false
         }
        },
        {
         is_bounced: {
          $ne: true
         }
        }
       ]
     },
      {
       $or: [
        {
        not_valid: {
          $exists: false
         }
        },
        {
        not_valid: {
          $ne: true
         }
        }
       ]
      }
    ]
   }
   }
  ],
  as: 'contact' }
 }, 
{
 $unwind: {
  path: '$contact',
  preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: false
 }
},
{
$addFields: {'contact.audience_id': '$contact_meta.audience_id'
}
}, 
{
 $replaceRoot: {newRoot: '$contact'
}
}])
```